# Is it possible to create a Restful webservice with POST requests in PHP without using any library?

Tags: php, json, rest, post

Basic requirement is to know if we can iterate through $_POST when the request body payload has data sent in json format e.g.

```
{"City":{"countryCode": "IN","regionCode":"KR"}}
```

We are able to access this only if we send the data as

```
m={"City":{"countryCode": "IN","regionCode":"KR"}}
```

We are able to access this using `$_POST['m']`
The Content-Type is set to default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, when we set this as `application/json` `$_POST` is empty/null.

If we try to access this as `$_POST` instead of `$_POST['m']` it returns null/empty.

**NB:** I am newbie to PHP. Is it possible to create webservices without any library. Without making use of any library can PHP accept the post request with json data.

Comment: The libraries are built using php, so why wouldn't you be able to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get raw POST data (as opposed to having to access individual POST variables such as $_POST['m']), you can use the following wrapper:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

You can read the manual on [wrappers](http://us.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) if you're interested in learning a bit more about them.

Comment: @Mike It can be XML or JSON or whatever. POST data is just data at the end of the day.

Comment: This reply is correct. A library does not enable a language like php with additional features, it just uses the in-built features in a more friendlier manner. Just to make breathing a little easy for developers.

Comment: @WayneWhitty thanks for the quick response. It works ! :) As suggested, shall read through the manual on wrappers.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i am getting data and saving it to my database.

```
 $return    = array();
 $data      = json_decode(stripslashes($_REQUEST['Data']));

 $email     = $data->{"paramA"};
 $password      = $data->{"paramB"};
```

i think it might help you.